# How do you get out of hell in TaskMaker?

Tags: taskmaker

In the classic Mac Game TaskMaker when your character dies, you get sent to a special 'hell' level. It seems impossible to escape from it. Is this intentional ? Or is there a way to resuscitate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TaskMaker#Gameplay) (under the *health* part), there is an exit in each corner, though only 1 can be open.  There should be a demon guarding this exit that you will need to fight before being able to leave.

> Hell is a maze lined with flaming walls containing 4 exits in each corner with a demon guard. Only one exit will be open and thus one demon to battle.

Comment: OK, you are right the north-eastern one is accessible.

Comment: If you end up in hell a second time, it may be a different corner.  I'm not sure if the choice is made upon entering a new game or the hell level (I also don't own a mac).  Speaking of which, +1 for finding a unique mac gaming question.